# Not receiving data from NSMutableURLRequest (iPhone app sync)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In the past, I created an iPhone app which relies on a sqlite database updated by a php page. When you access the PHP page, it prints out a dump of a sqlite database and the app runs the various queries to update the sqlite database. My previous app worked fine in this manner and would update accordingly. I recently tried to apply the same process to a new app with a much bigger database. I have run into problems.

What I am doing is sending some post variables to a PHP page which recognizes the POST and echoes out the sqlite commands to update the database. The problem is that it takes a few seconds for the page to print the commands. If I have the page print some static text, I get it in my NSLog(@"Response data is going to be ==> %@", result); command. If I have to extract the information from my MySQL database, it takes about 3-5 seconds and then prints (on my normal browser). When I run the app, however, it says that Response data is going to be ==> (null) instead of the commands.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be happening? I know that this works when it doesn't print a lot of stuff and when it is static. The dynamic part makes it return null for some reason.

Help appreciated.

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlBase]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSData *post = [myParameters dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[post length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:post];
    [request setHTTPBody:[myParameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set headers
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text/plain"];

    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                                 returningResponse:&urlResponse 
                                                             error:&error];

    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response data is going to be ==> %@", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to understand this code..it helps u.

```
NSString *soapMessage=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" YOUR WEB SERVICE CODE",myTxt1.text,myTxt2.text];

NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);

//-----------create connection

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://your local host webservice url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString *msgLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];
```

//----------sending request

```
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/AutenticateUser" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

//[activityIndicator startAnimating];

```
if ( theConnection )

{
webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code, but even after implementing it, I am not getting any data back from my webpage, not even static stuff now. Before I was getting data fine, it was just a matter of a timeout I think. Now, it will not even give me my static content.

Comment: you have to check NSLog in output window that what coming back in web data. Or paste your output.so I can check.Output should be ur soap result.